# How to show only fix records in the yii2 gridview

Tags: yii2

I am working with yii2 Framework. I want only few records in gridview where status = 1 in database[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utMdO.png)

This is the screen shot of gridview I want only highlighted records whose status is 1
This Code of view page is -:

```
<p>All Issued Devices are Highlighted   </p>
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\models\DeviceTrackerSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

//$this->title = 'Tracked Devices';
//$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<b style="font-size: 30px;">ALL ISSUED DEVICES ARE HIGHLIGHTED   </b>
<div class="device-tracker-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'rowOptions'=>function($model)
         {
          if($model->status == '1')
          {
              return ['class'=>'info'];
          }
          else
          {
              return ['class'=>'default'];
          }


        },

        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'attribute'=>'devices_device_id',
                'value'=>'devicesDevice.device_name'



            ],
            //'id',
            //'devices_device_id',
            'user_first_name',
            'user_last_name',
            'email_address:email',
            // 'user_department',
             'assign_date',
             'return_date',
             //'status',
             //'Issued_by',
            [

              'attribute'=>'Issued_by' ,
              'value'=>'issuedBy.first_name'
            ],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

Please Tell me how to solve the problem?

Controller action is-

```
 public function actionReturn()
    {
       // echo "welcome";die;
        if(isset(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_type))
        {
        $status = Yii::$app->user->identity->user_type;
        if($status == 1)
        {
        $this->layout = 'headerLayoutSuperadmin';
        $searchModel = new DeviceTrackerSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index1', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
        }
        else
        { 
        $this->layout = 'headerLayout';
        $searchModel = new DeviceTrackerSearch();
        $dataProvider =    $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index1', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]); 
        }
        }
        else
        {

             return $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
        }

    }
```

sql search models-:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use frontend\models\DeviceTracker;

/**
 * DeviceTrackerSearch represents the model behind the search form about `frontend\models\DeviceTracker`.
 */
class DeviceTrackerSearch extends DeviceTracker
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id',  'status', 'Issued_by'], 'integer'],
            [['user_first_name', 'devices_device_id', 'user_last_name', 'email_address', 'user_department', 'assign_date', 'return_date'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = DeviceTracker::find();
         //$query = DeviceTracker::findAll('status=>1');
        // print_r($query);die;
         //echo $query;die;
        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }
        $query->joinWith('devicesDevice');
        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            //'devices_device_id' => $this->devices_device_id,
            'assign_date' => $this->assign_date,
            'return_date' => $this->return_date,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'Issued_by' => $this->Issued_by,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_first_name', $this->user_first_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_last_name', $this->user_last_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email_address', $this->email_address])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_department', $this->user_department])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'devices.device_name', $this->devices_device_id]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried? This is not a programming solution service site.

Comment: which data type is status field?

Comment: Status is integer data type Either 1 or 0

Comment: Like I want to show only rows whose status = 1

Comment: in your dataProvider get only the filtered data, put your requirement in your WHERE condition of query and you are done.

Comment: I which file Do I need to add code. Please can you send the code?

Comment: I had posted an answer but deleted it because my response was criticized by someone who believes I copied it from her .. I hope you solve your problem. If you can not get me within a certain time let me make a comment  at @scaisedge that I see to solve it later ... good work

Comment: Thank You Sir. Problem has been solved. Thanks for Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your search model, update the query to suit the output you want to pass to view.
something like this for the current condition i.e. you want to display only those rows whose status is 1

so,

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            //'devices_device_id' => $this->devices_device_id,
            'assign_date' => $this->assign_date,
            'return_date' => $this->return_date,
            'status' => 1, // **this is where you are filtering the data with status == 1**
            'Issued_by' => $this->Issued_by,
        ]);
```

and brief explanation of flow is

- your controller which calls the dataProvider, gives you data that you pass to view and then eventually to gridView
- the data is stored in mysql tables, so whatever data you want to send to view you need to query it in the searchModel in dataProvider's query
- return dataProvide to controller > view > gridWidget

Comment: Thank you Sir. It's working fine. Now I am clear about the flow. Thank You